# Setting a Custom HeaderView on UITable in swift, using AutoLayout from Nib

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, autolayout

Hi I was wondering how i'd go for implementing a custom header for my `UITableView` and use it's autolayout for correct positioning.

I can display the cell right now but neither horizontal or vertical autolayout is applied.

in my tableViewController, I set a headerView variable to my custom nib as such:

```
@IBOutlet var view: UIView!

override init(frame: CGRect) { // for using CustomView in code
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.setup()
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { // for using CustomView in IB
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.setup()
}

private func setup() {
    NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomHeader", owner: self, options: nil)
    self.addSubview(view)
}
```

which in the view class calls:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) { // for using CustomView in code
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.setup()
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { // for using CustomView in IB
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.setup()
}

private func setup() {
    NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ChallengeHeader", owner: self, options: nil)
    self.addSubview(view)
}
```

It has some dummy content and I set a dynamic text to a label inside. The constraints are set up correctly I have it working fine for the table cells.

I have this for displaying the view as header

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if let view = headerView {
        return view
    }
    return nil
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if let head = headerView {
        head.setNeedsLayout()
        head.layoutIfNeeded()
        let height = head.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height

        let headerFrame = head.frame


        Debug.log("Header Height \(height)")
        return 100.0
    }
    return 0
}
```

Currently I'm returning the 100.0 since height is always 0, so what am I missing here to make the autolayout do it's work? Or do I need to set f/e the width programmatically?

Edit: Forgot to add, the xib has a width of 400 and it seems to remain 400 width aswell.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few problems with your implementation.

First, you should not add the `headerView` as subview of `self.view`.

Second, if you have more than one sections, you would need a new CustomView for every section, you should not reuse it.

So your code should look something like:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomHeader", owner: nil, options: nil)[0] as? UIView
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return headerView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
}
```

You don't need any frame manipulation. Just make sure you return a correctly initialized `CustomHeader` in the `viewForHeaderInSection` and everything should work fine.

If you need more help or support, just let me know.

---

This is a small code snippet that I used to test - the only difference to your situation is that you load the headerView from the xib:

```
override func viewDidLoad (){

    headerView = UIView.new() // here you should have your xib loading

    var insideView = UIView.new();
    insideView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    headerView.addSubview(insideView);

    // This is simulating the constraints you have in your xib  
    headerView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[view(50)]-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["view": insideView]))     
    headerView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[view]-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["view": insideView]))
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return headerView
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return headerView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
}
```

Comment: I need something like frame manipulation because it's an auto layout file.

I also don't have more than 1 section so re-using it seems like a good idea to me. I'll look into the other suggestions, it might help.

The view is unlimited in height since it contains some user generated content.

Comment: I have updated my answer. This should work, if your constraints are set right in the xib file, for the height. The important thing is that the headerView's height must be determined from it's subviews, using the right constraints. If it does not work, you can post some more information about your constraints and i'll be happy to help

Comment: this: First, you should not add the headerView as subview of self.view.

What would be the proper solution then? I havent seen any other ways todo this yet, might be because my head was too busy getting really intimate with the wall.

Comment: you should not add it to anything, it will be added automatically to the tableView since you implemented the delegate methods

Comment: Ah, the addSubView is inside the custom UIView (headerView) after instantiating. I'll report back when I debug some more.

Comment: I added some code snipped I used to test. The headerView should not be added to any subview, it will be added to the tableView by the framework

Comment: Any Change you'd be able to add how your xib's class is structured? I'll expand what I have. When I remove the addSubview part the view is empty currently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75732/discussion-between-mathijs-segers-and-catalina-t).